# How to declare an UMD module which only expose one function?

Tags: typescript, global-variables, umd, .d.ts, typescript-definitions

Here's what I currently have:

```
export default function (bar?: any): Foo

export as namespace qux;
```

Assuming we have no module loader, what should I change so that `qux` may be called directly?
What I am trying to avoid is: `qux.default()`
In short I want the global variable to match the default export.

<sub>(of course `import defaultName from 'qux'; defaultName()` should continue to work)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Exportation

```
export = qux;
export as namespace qux;

declare function qux(bar?: any): Foo

interface Foo {}
```

### Importation

#### .ts file

```
import defaultName = require('qux');
```

#### .js file

```
import defaultName from 'qux';
```